# how to get the count of specific field from different objects in an array in JS

Tags: javascript

```
var Universities = [{
    "State": "ILLINOIS",
    "University": "North Park University",
    "Place": "Chicago"
}, {
    "State": "VERMONT",
    "University": "University of Vermont",
    "Place": "Berlington"
}, {
    "State": "FLORIDA",
    "University": "North Wood University",
    "Place": "Midland"
}, {
    "State": "NEW YORK",
    "University": "Pace State University(undergradations& post graduations",
    "Place": "NY"
}, {
    "State": "ILLINOIS",
    "University": "University of North Alabama",
    "Place": "Florence"
}, {
    "State": "ILLINOIS",
    "University": "Louisiana Technology University",
    "Place": "Ruston"
}, {
    "State": "North Carolina",
    "University": "East Carolina University",
    "Place": "Green Ville"
}, {
    "State": "ARKANSAS",
    "University": "Arkansas State University",
    "Place": "Jones boro"
}, {
    "State": "Oklahoma",
    "University": "University of Tulsa",
    "Place": "Tulsa"
}, {
    "State": "ILLINOIS",
    "University": "Rush University",
    "Place": "Chicago"
}]
```

How many `UNIVERSITIES` are there in `ILLINOIS` state?
Please check and help me out.

Comment: need a code to get the count of specific filed

Comment: And what is that you've tried? Stack Overflow isn't a *give me the code* service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the how-to-ask tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count occurances in string from keyword array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400235/count-occurances-in-string-from-keyword-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly , maybe use `filter` can figure it out :

```
var result = Universities.filter(function (ele) {
    return ele.State == 'ILLINOIS';
});

console.log(result);
```